# Escape @ sign in Domino Lotus Notes

Tags: escaping, lotus-domino

I want to search documents containing `@` in specified field (e.g., [From]) in Domino Lotus Notes. How to do this? When I place just `@` it throws an error. When I place here anything more, e.g., `1@`, it works.

Application version: IBM Notes 9 Social Edition (Version  9.0.1).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the @ in "".

e.g.

```
FIELD From CONTAINS "@"
```

Comment: I have tried that and this throws an error whereas ```FIELD From CONTAINS "1@"```  returns two documents.

Comment: Works for me... where do you try and what version of Notes do you use? In fulltext search even [From] = "@" and [From] = @ work for me...

Comment: In the fulltext search bar. I tried both these options and received the following error: "Full-text error". I mentioned the LN version I am using in the main post.

Comment: Try recreating the Full Text Index.  Use the default options.